# findOne({key:value}) or findOne().where({key:value}) when querying database with waterline?

Tags: mysql, orm, sails.js, waterline

I'm using [Waterline](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline) to query MySQL database by Sails. I found 2 ways to do that.
I don't know which one is better?
By the way, how to handle error for both case?

```
1. Model.findOne().where({key: value}).then(function(data){
      console.log(data);})

2. Phase.findOne({key: value}).then(function(data){
      console.log(phase);})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either will work. In that method you catch an error as seen below.

```
1. Model.findOne().where({key: value}).then(function(data){
      console.log(data);}).catch(function(err){/*....*/})

2. Phase.findOne({key: value}).then(function(data){
      console.log(phase);}).catch(function(err){/*....*/})
```

Another option

```
Phase.findOne({key: value}).exec(function(err, data){
    if(err) /* Do something with error */  
    console.log(phase);
})
```

Also, if your searching by the Primary Key then you can do

```
Phase.findOne(PK)
```

https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/query.md#query-language